# Dividing students into teams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So this is the question :

Count the number of ways in which you can divide a group of 33 students into 3 soccer teams 
(each team has 11 students, them have no names).

I know that I shouldn't use the stars and bars formula because order is important in this 
case, but still not sure how I should do it properly, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just choose $11$ for your first team then choose $11$ to the second team and then the last $11$ are given. You have 
$$\binom{33}{11}\binom{22}{11}.$$
But you don't care which $11$ was choosen when, so you must divide by $3!$.
We get
$$\frac{\binom{33}{11}\binom{22}{11}}{6}.$$